# Android : transfer a view from a parent to another one

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view

I come here help since I don't understand at all my my code isn't working.
To be quick, my goal is to "reload" a View that represents a list item. Since my list item can contain other list items in it's children, I want to inflate a new list item, and then transfer those children from the old one to the new one.

I get a "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." error, but I do call a removeView on the child's parent (somehow it doesn't work) (see my code after)

Here is how my layout is designed (I'm removing some lines so it is more readable) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainListItem"
            type="com.plg.lirs.data.LirsDataEntity" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_list_item_global_layout">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_list_item_parent_layout"
            app:mainListItemParentLayout="@{mainListItem}">

        <!-- contains a bunch of views and stuff, nothing important here -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main_list_item_children_layout"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <!-- here are all the children i want to transfer, all the children here are inflated from this layout -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Now here my code to inflate this layout :

```kotlin
/* entity is just a logical class that contains my data
olderView is the old view representing the old list item */
private fun inflateItem(entity: LirsDataEntity, olderView: View? = null) : View {
        val itemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<MainListItemBinding>(inflater, R.layout.main_list_item, null, false, null)
       // the itemBinding.root will be added into the parent's children layout later on, after this function
       // + i've tried with true as attachToParent, doesn't change

       /* HERE is the core of the problem. My goal is : if an olderView is provided, then transfer the children from the old one to the new one */
        if(olderView != null) {
            val olderChildrenLayout = olderView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.main_list_item_children_layout) // here is the LinearLayout that contains the children
            val children = olderChildrenLayout.children
            children.forEach {
                olderChildrenLayout.removeView(it) // remove the children from the old parent
                itemBinding.mainListItemChildrenLayout.addView(it) // add it to the new parent
                // at this point i get the error
            }
        }

        entity.ui.reset() // not important here
        itemBinding.mainListItem = entity 

        /* some listeners are set here */

        return itemBinding.root
    }
```

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out what were wrong.
When calling removeView(), android tries to animate it, thus placing the child view into a variable containing the children that are currently being animated. Then, when trying to change the child view's parent (which we want to be null), it checks it the current view is being animated. As it's true, the parent doesn't change (for now at least, I don't know if it will be changed later on). That's why we can't call the addView().

The solution is to store the LayoutTransition class, then setting it to null, do the transfer, and then resetting it. It will not animate the children, but at least it will work.

Here is a little piece of code to make that work:

```
public class JavaUtils {
    public static void transferChildren(@NotNull final ViewGroup depart, @NotNull final ViewGroup arrival) {
        LayoutTransition transition = depart.getLayoutTransition();
        depart.setLayoutTransition(null);
            while(depart.getChildCount() > 0) {
            View c = depart.getChildAt(0);
            depart.removeViewAt(0);
            arrival.addView(c);
        }
        depart.setLayoutTransition(transition);
    }
}
```

And for Kotlin users :

```
fun ViewGroup.transferChildrenTo(arrival: ViewGroup) {
    val transition: LayoutTransition = layoutTransition
    layoutTransition = null
    while (childCount > 0) {
        val c: View = getChildAt(0)
        removeViewAt(0)
        arrival.addView(c)
    }
    layoutTransition = transition
}
```